# Работа primary key и hibernate при исключениях

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Учу связь one-to-one на примере однонаправленных отношений.
Есть два java-класса (`Employee` и `Details`). У обоих классов в таблице есть поле `id` (*primary key* для `Employee` и *foreign key* для `Details`). Я создала объекты этих классов, соединила их через сеттер, и добавила основной объект в базу:

```
    Employee emp = new Employee("Ivan", "Ivanov", "IT", 500);
    Details detail = new Detail("Omsk", "+7000000");
    emp.setEmpDetail(detail);
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(emp);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Т.к. в классе `Employee` я не прописала каскад для аннотации `@OneToOne`, то вылетел эксшепшн и объекты в базу не добавились. После того, как я подправила код и прописала каскад, все заработало, однако *primary key* для объекта `emp` был равен 2 вместо 1.
Подскажите, почему так вышло и можно ли прописать код для актуализации *primary key* на случай исключительных ситуаций (к примеру, если объект не был создан, то вычесть единицу)?

Comment: *можно ли прописать код для актуализации primary key на случай исключительных ситуаций (к примеру, если объект не был создан, то вычесть единицу)?* Вы не понимаете, что такое PRIMARY KEY. То, что Вы хотите - это самый что ни на есть криминальный криминал. Не следует вмешиваться в работу автоинкрементного первичного ключа, никогда и ни при каких обстоятельствах. Более того, в реальности не существует надобности даже просто видеть его значение - и уж тем более как-то влиять на него.

Comment: @Akina спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то у вас так вышло, потому что у вас исключение выскочило до вашего коммита и соответственно сессия не закрылась. Для предотвращения подобных ситуаций рекомендую оборачивать данный код в try-catch-finally блоки. И в блоке finally закрывать сессию. В таком случае вы исключите подобную ситуацию, так как даже в случае экзепшена, ваш finally блок отработает и закроет сессию.
При добавлении нового работника, ваш primary key должен актуализироваться.
Если не прав, заранее прошу прощения и надеюсь меня более опытные ребята подправят, потому что я сам как раз на этом месте прохожу Спринг)

Comment: Спасибо! Проверила, действительно дело оказалось именно в этом)